# What is the countable product sigma algebra of powersets of a countable set $E$? The powerset of the space of all sequences in $E$ or not?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a countable set with power set $\mathcal{P}(E)$. $(E,\mathcal{P}(E))$ is a measurable space. Let $E^{\mathbb{N}}$ be the space of sequences in $E$ and $\mathcal{P}(E)^{\mathbb{N}}$ the product sigma algebra generated by the projections $\pi_i:E^\mathbb{N}\to (E,\mathcal{P}(E)) ,\;(\omega_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\mapsto \omega_j$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then $(E^\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(E)^\mathbb{N})$ is a measurable space, but what is $\mathcal{P}(E)^\mathbb{N}$? Is it equal to the power set $\mathcal{P}(E^\mathbb{N})$ of $E^\mathbb{N}$ or not and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Borel sigma algebra on the Baire space which is homeomorphic to irrationals. So there can be at most continuum many such sets. Here's the wiki article about Baire space: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_(set_theory)